# Yarn log aggregation of spark streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

By default, YARN aggregates logs after an application completes. But I am trying to aggregate logs for spark streaming job which in theory will run forever. I have set the following properties for log aggregation and restarted yarn by restarting `hadoop-yarn-nodemanager` for core & task nodes and `hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager` for master node on my emr cluster. I can view my changes in http://node-ip:8088/conf.

```
yarn.log-aggregation-enable => true
yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds => 172800
yarn.log-aggregation.retain-check-interval-seconds => -1
yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.roll-monitoring-interval-seconds => 3600
```

All the articles and resources have only mentioned to include `yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.roll-monitoring-interval-seconds` property and yarn will start aggregating logs for running jobs. But it is not working in my case.

Comment: I guess (not confident) that yarn log aggregation feature works only for MapReduce jobs, not Spark or any other processing engine.

Comment: My logs are aggregating once the job is killed/finish but not while the job is running